# How to dynamically load generated html with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am making a website using HTML, CSS and Javascript. What I'm currently trying to do is making a Javascript that simplifies the way to add more 'items' to a website. For example a store item. Please see http://nl.tinypic.com/r/t5khtf/9.

Those are 3 items that I am adding in this Javascript. However, it keeps telling me that the items are UNDEFINED...
Here is the code from the JavaScript http://pastebin.com/hjL9MByY.
Here is how I load it into a div:

```
<div id="store_beatles_eps"></div>
```

How do I fix this?
Any help would be very much appreciated. 
If I made any mistakes in the question, please report that to me and I'll change it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use wrong variable. Instead of this:

```
function generateStoreItem(item)
  ... 
  r = r.replace("{{page}}", store_beatles_eps.itemPage);
```

you should have

```
function generateStoreItem(item)
   ... 
   r = r.replace("{{page}}", item.itemPage);
```

And yet, while ago I did simple repeatable() jQuery plugin for that purpose: 
https://github.com/c-smile/repeatable

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It is fixed now!